# How to fade out then direct to a new page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was just wondering how to fade out the page when clicked and open up another html page. Right now I have

```
<div class="menu-item color">
  <a href="html/webmap.html">
    <i class="fa fa-flask"></i>
    <p>Webmap</p>
  </a>
</div>
```

How can I make it so that when "Webmap" menu item is clicked, the page fades out and opens up my webmap.html page?

I know javascript is invovled, I just can't figure it out!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a whole lot to explain :

```
$(function() {

  $('.menu-item a').click(function() {

    var destination = this.href;

    $('body').fadeOut('slow', function() {

      window.location = destination;
    });

    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to apply a quick fade in after it fades out?

Comment: Do you mean on the redirected page? That would need a bit of script *there*. For example, hide `body` by default with CSS and use `fadeIn` when the new page has loaded. It would be independent of the current document that's open. Unless they're linked with `localStorage` but that would overcomplicate.

Comment: I mean after it fades out, is there a way for it to quickly fade in and then jump to the page?

Comment: Sure, you could add another callback inside the existing one : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pjxJoQ?editors=001.

Comment: Thank you so much! I truly appreciate it :D!

Comment: Actually, fading is synchronous so only a single callback would be needed. http://tinyurl.com/onyy6w2